# Error In Query Operation: Cannot start a job without a project id

Tags: google-bigquery

I keep getting an error using the bqcommand line tool. For example, I can easily run this query and it returns the table that I want:

```
head -n 10 xxxx-bq:name_name.Report2
```

Note that xxxx-bq is the projectid, and name_name is the dataset id. When I try to run a query against this table, say the follwing:

```
query "SELECT count(*) FROM xxxx-bq:name_name.Report2
```

I get an error that says that I cannot start a job without a project id. What am I doing wrong here? How can I specify in the query the project ID? I know people have asked some similar questions. That said, I have been following along and my approach is not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have a project id? If not, this page can help you set one up: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/bq-command-line-tool-quickstart

All BigQuery jobs (which include queries) require a project id, which is the project that gets billed for any damage done by the job. (by damage, I mean work)
You should either set your default project id (you can do this by running bq init)
or set the project id that you're running the job under via --project_id=

So if you're running `bq shell`, you would use `bq shell --project_id=myprojectid` instead.

Comment: Great point. I do have a project id. What I ended up doing was setting the project as my default in the default config file for BQ. Then, I was able to cleanly execute queries. This should work nicely as a start. Thanks Jordan for the help!

Answer (score 0):

strange... I just started working with bq & got the same error but it didn't like me passing `--project_id=[myprojectid]`. Although I was already authed with `gcloud auth login`, I had to run `bq init` (and it seemingly didn't do anything) -- after that, my queries worked just fine.